# filter dataframe where a value stays under a threshold for specified amount of time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataset which is described as follows:

```
timestamp,y
2019-08-01 00:00:00,772.0
2019-08-01 00:15:00,648.0
2019-08-01 00:30:00,652.0
2019-08-01 00:45:00,572.0
2019-08-01 01:00:00,604.0
2019-08-01 01:15:00,644.0
2019-08-01 01:30:00,544.0
...
```

What I am doing at the moment is filtering the dataframe where the values are under a specified threshold using something like:

```
filtered = df[lambda x: x["y"] < some_threshold]
```

However, what I would like is to get the rows where the threshold condition is met and remains like that for at least an hour i.e. 4 data points. So, in my example if the threshold is set to `650`, it should return the last 4 rows and not the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make your data worth looking at:

```
df.loc[7] = ['2019-08-01 5:30:00', 900]
df.loc[8] = ['2019-08-01 8:30:00', 500]
df.loc[9] = ['2019-08-01 12:30:00', 900]
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df = df.resample('15T').interpolate()
print(df)

# Output:
                          y
timestamp
2019-08-01 00:00:00  772.00
2019-08-01 00:15:00  648.00
2019-08-01 00:30:00  652.00
2019-08-01 00:45:00  572.00
2019-08-01 01:00:00  604.00
2019-08-01 01:15:00  644.00
2019-08-01 01:30:00  544.00
2019-08-01 01:45:00  566.25
2019-08-01 02:00:00  588.50
2019-08-01 02:15:00  610.75
2019-08-01 02:30:00  633.00
2019-08-01 02:45:00  655.25
2019-08-01 03:00:00  677.50
2019-08-01 03:15:00  699.75
2019-08-01 03:30:00  722.00
2019-08-01 03:45:00  744.25
2019-08-01 04:00:00  766.50
2019-08-01 04:15:00  788.75
2019-08-01 04:30:00  811.00
2019-08-01 04:45:00  833.25
2019-08-01 05:00:00  855.50
2019-08-01 05:15:00  877.75
2019-08-01 05:30:00  900.00
2019-08-01 05:45:00  866.67
2019-08-01 06:00:00  833.33
2019-08-01 06:15:00  800.00
2019-08-01 06:30:00  766.67
2019-08-01 06:45:00  733.33
2019-08-01 07:00:00  700.00
2019-08-01 07:15:00  666.67
2019-08-01 07:30:00  633.33
2019-08-01 07:45:00  600.00
2019-08-01 08:00:00  566.67
2019-08-01 08:15:00  533.33
2019-08-01 08:30:00  500.00
2019-08-01 08:45:00  525.00
2019-08-01 09:00:00  550.00
2019-08-01 09:15:00  575.00
2019-08-01 09:30:00  600.00
2019-08-01 09:45:00  625.00
2019-08-01 10:00:00  650.00
2019-08-01 10:15:00  675.00
2019-08-01 10:30:00  700.00
2019-08-01 10:45:00  725.00
2019-08-01 11:00:00  750.00
2019-08-01 11:15:00  775.00
2019-08-01 11:30:00  800.00
2019-08-01 11:45:00  825.00
2019-08-01 12:00:00  850.00
2019-08-01 12:15:00  875.00
2019-08-01 12:30:00  900.00
```

Now we can apply some rolling logic, we'll count values if they're less than 650. If the count makes it to 4, then all fours and the 3 values before each 4, are what we want:

```
out = df[df.lt(650)
           .rolling('h')
           .sum()
           .eq(4)
           .replace(False, np.nan)
           .bfill(limit=3)
           .fillna(False)
           .values]
print(out)

# Output:
                              y
timestamp
2019-08-01 00:45:00  572.000000
2019-08-01 01:00:00  604.000000
2019-08-01 01:15:00  644.000000
2019-08-01 01:30:00  544.000000
2019-08-01 01:45:00  566.250000
2019-08-01 02:00:00  588.500000
2019-08-01 02:15:00  610.750000
2019-08-01 02:30:00  633.000000
2019-08-01 07:30:00  633.333333
2019-08-01 07:45:00  600.000000
2019-08-01 08:00:00  566.666667
2019-08-01 08:15:00  533.333333
2019-08-01 08:30:00  500.000000
2019-08-01 08:45:00  525.000000
2019-08-01 09:00:00  550.000000
2019-08-01 09:15:00  575.000000
2019-08-01 09:30:00  600.000000
2019-08-01 09:45:00  625.000000
```

Comment: Oh, so cool. Thanks! Can you explain why we need the `rolling`?

Comment: Run just `df.lt(650).rolling('h').sum()` and look at the output. Rolling ensures our sum never goes above 4... because the window size that it's rolling with is 4~

Comment: I guess also making `rolling(4)` is a good idea for readability or making this a parameter.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to convey, 4 happens to be the number of periods in an hour in your data, If you had closer/further time intervals, or they weren't even, this would be different/more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```py
import numpy as np

time_delta = 1 # [unit: hours]

# convert timestamp
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# forward: check where the condition is met
boolList = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    boolList.append(df[(df['timestamp'] <= row['timestamp']) & (abs(df['timestamp'] - row['timestamp']) / np.timedelta64(time_delta, 'h') < time_delta)]['y'].agg(max) < some_threshold)

# backward: set corresponding previous rows to True 
df['bool'] = boolList
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['bool']):
        df.loc[(df['timestamp'] < row['timestamp']) & (abs(df['timestamp'] - row['timestamp']) / np.timedelta64(time_delta, 'h') < time_delta), 'bool']=True
        
    
# filter
filtered = df[df['bool']][['timestamp', 'y']]
filtered
```

yielding

|  | timestamp | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2019-08-01 00:45:00 | 572.0 |
| 4 | 2019-08-01 01:00:00 | 604.0 |
| 5 | 2019-08-01 01:15:00 | 644.0 |
| 6 | 2019-08-01 01:30:00 | 544.0 |

### Explanation

For the sake of readability, the solution is not provided via list comprehensions.

It leveraged [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `np.timedelta64()` to filter those rows that fall within the previous hour. Subsequently, the observations `y` are assessed by checking if their respective maximum is below `some_threshold`. If so, the respective entry in `boolList` is set to `True` indicating that the entries of the previous hour all satisfied the condition. A second loop is required to mark those entries, that fell within one of those intervals: `df['bool']` indicates all valid row entries.
Finally, the `df` is filtered according to this `bool` column that is dropped from `filtered`.

The code hinges on [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `np.timedelta64()` to filter those rows that fall within the previous hour. Then, it assesses if each of the corresponding observations `y` is below the given value `some_threshold`. If this is true for each observation, the respective maximum of this subset will lie below it, too, justifying `agg(max)`.

### Generality

The dataframe you provided indicates observations that are sampled uniformly across time (every 15 minutes). Regardless, my proposed solution does not assume that this holds true for your entire dataframe. You can change the time interval via `time_delta`. However, `nan` entries in the `timestamp` or `y` column require additional work.

Comment: You're just checking if that the timestamp is after 1 o'clock, not if the value is staying below the threshold for at least 1 hour. ("where the threshold condition is met and remains like that for at least an hour")

Comment: Thank you, great point. I misunderstood the question. Let me re-consider.

Comment: You can copy OPs data simply with `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`, I hope you didn't retype all that :')